# Get last 5 binary bits from a binary number?

Tags: c

I have a binary number (e.g 111001001). I am trying to get last 5 digits (01001). How can i do this? i thought to store each digit to an arrray and then get the values with a for loop. But is there any better way?

Comment: masking? `foo = bar & yourmask`?

Comment: It depends on what you wnat to do with the digits. Just applying a mask with bitwise-and (`&`) is what comes to mind, but that still leaves the bits "packed" into a single integer.

Comment: i am learning now c and i have no idea what is masking! i will google it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get just the last 5 bits by masking:

```
x = x & 0x1f;
```

If you want to *process* each of these bits then you can test them individually in a loop, e.g.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    if (x & (1 << i))  // if bit i is set
    {
        // do something for bit i = 1
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else for bit i = 0
    }
}
```

(Note: no need to mask first in this case.)

Comment: And make sure that i is an unsigned type for added sign-bit safety.

Comment: @Jens: that is a good general suggestion when working with bitwise operators, but it doesn't actually matter in this particular case.

Answer (score 10):

Just use a bitmask:

```
int val = value & 0x1F;
```

Explanation:

```
  1 1100 1001 ---> your value
  0 0001 1111 ---> the bitmask
       1    F ---> hexadecimal equivalent of the bitmask
  -----------
& 0 0000 1001 ---> value & bitmask
```

The binary & (AND) operation has the following truth table:

```
┌─────╥───┬───┐
│ A&B ║ 0 │ 1 │
╞═════╬═══╪═══╡
│  0  ║ 0 │ 0 │
├─────╫───┼───┤
│  1  ║ 0 │ 1 │
└─────╨───┴───┘
```

Only bits which are 1 in the value and the bitmask become 1 in the result.
This effectively allows you to control which bits you want to keep from the value.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `number & 31`.

`31` = `11111` in binary